# Samsung NVMe 980 PRO and Alfais 4390 M.2 Nvme Ssd Ngff To Pcie 3.0 X16 compatibility

Tags: hardware-acceleration, pci-e, solid-state-drive, nvme, samsung

Dear Friends I need help.
Is the following combination compatible?
What will be the maximum write and read speed I will get, AS MegaBytes?
I will be glad to hear for your comments.

[1- Samsung NVMe 980 PRO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGPHb.jpg)

[2- Alfais 4390 M.2 Nvme Ssd Ngff To Pcie 3.0 X16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEMVu.jpg)

[3- PCIE GEN3 x 16 Slot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQzgv.jpg)

Expectation ?
Write: about 5000 MB/S
Read : about 6000 MB/S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NVMe drive you list has a PCIe 4.0 connection with four lanes although your riser and slot are only PCIe 3.0 so you'll be limited to Gen 3 speeds.

According to Wikipedia, the expected throughput for a PCIe Gen3 x4 connection, you can see up to 3.938 GB/s speeds. Note that this is maximum throughput, you will most likely never see those speeds due to the overhead of the protocol and going through the operating system.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#History_and_revisions

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are right. I tried it and i got the same result as you said.